# Issue comparing two functions

Tags: c++, arduino, rtti

I’m writing an Arduino library (RTTI is not available on the Arduino platform) whose purpose is to mimic the event system of the action script 3 language but being new to c++ I’m facing some issues I didn’t expect when I start this project :-)

To be concise this system is based on the trio: Event / Event Dispatcher / Event Listener. Event (or subclasses of Event) are dispatched by an Event Dispatcher and Event listeners are callback function that takes a single parameter of type Event. Whenever an Event is dispatched, every listeners of this Event type is called.

Here is a minimalist example code (no implementation of the real dispatching process) to show how it works :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Event
{

public:
    std::string type;

    Event(std::string type) : type(type){}
};


class FanEvent : public Event
{

public:
    int fanRPM;

    FanEvent(std::string type, int fanRPM)
            : Event::Event(type), fanRPM(fanRPM){}
};

class EventListener
{

public:
    std::function<void(Event *)> _listener;
    std::string type;

    EventListener(std::string type, std::function<void(Event *)> listener)
            :type(type), _listener(listener){};
};


class ControllerBase
{

private:

    std::vector<EventListener *> _eventListeners;

public:

    void addEventlistener(std::string eventType, std::function<void(Event *)> listener)
    {
        _eventListeners.push_back(new EventListener(eventType, listener));
    };

    void dispatchEvent(Event *event)
    {
        _eventListeners[0]->_listener(event);
    }
};

class FanController : public ControllerBase
{

public:

    void init()
    {
        addEventlistener("speedChange", [this](Event *event)
        {
            this->updateFanStatus(static_cast<FanEvent *>(event));
        });
    }

    void simulateEventDispatching()
    {
        dispatchEvent(new FanEvent("speedChange", 1200));
    };

    void updateFanStatus(FanEvent *event)
    {

        std::cout << "Fan RPM :" << event->fanRPM << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    FanController fanController;
    fanController.init();
    fanController.simulateEventDispatching();
    return 0;
}
```

The console output is

> Fan RPM : 1200

So on the principle it’s working but I have two issues with the implementation of the real event dispatching process :

- I would like to prevent an eventListener to be added to the std::vector if the latest already contains an Event listener pointing to the same listener function but I can’t find a way to tell if two std::function are the same.
- An Event is distributed to a listener if the std::string type value of the EventListener instance that point to this listener is equal to the std::string type value of the Event. But I would like to check that the Event Class type of the Event is the same that the Event Class Type parameter of the Listener : Let say you have an CustomEventA Class and a CustomEventB class and a listener that register to a CustomEventA with the string type = « change ». I don’t want that listener to be notified if a CustomEventB with the string type = « change » is dispatched.

Comment: What do you mean by "*[...] if the latest already contains an Event listener pointing to the same listener function [...]*"? You can't quite compare functions, especially ones which are initialized with lambdas. Consider this code: `auto x1 = []() { }; auto x2 = []() { }; std::cout << (x1 == x2);` which outputs `0`.

Comment: [`std::function::target`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target)? Granted, One could only use it to check if function pointers are equal.

Comment: The target property seems to be not available here : 'class std::function<void(Event*)>' has no member named 'target'

Comment: @Fureeish I mean that it should be impossible to add an Event Listener with the same string type value pointing to the same listener function more than once. So I'm looking for a way to compare the _listener property of the EventListener class

Comment: Do unique `_listener`s come with unique `type`s? I'm talking about the fields of `EventListener`.

Comment: @Fureeish yes _listener stores a std::function<void(Event *)> . I would like to be able to compare the _listener property between to EventListener instances

Comment: You can't meaningfully compare `std::function`. I asked whether one function is associated with one type. If yes, forget about the existance of the function and compare the `std::string type` fields. If not, it's not possible.

Comment: @Fureeish no, it's not possible because several controllers instance can be registered to the same  std::string type

Comment: Then you cannot do what you want to do, unfortunately. Given two `std::function`s of the same signature, you cannot tell whether they point to the same function. They are *uncomparable*, period. I suggest you rethink your design.

Comment: Is there a way to store in the EventListener instance the adress of the _listener method ?

Comment: I do not believe so. Each function is of a different type.

Comment: @Fureeish thank you for your time.